# Finding a way to push_back matched key and values from a map into vector

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I had code that was similar to this in Java, but getting it to work in C++ is a different story. Currently, this function does find the key correctly and pushes the key to the back of my vector. I would like to grab both the key and its pair of values to all be inserted into the same index of the vector. I have looked into using a pair for my vector so it would be (key, pair of values), which I am not sure I am able to do.

```
vector<string> getIfPresentPartOfSpeech(multimap<string, pair<string, string>> dictionary, string name) {
    vector<string> response;
    auto it = dictionary.begin();
    while (it != dictionary.end()) {
        // Check if value of this entry matches with given value
        if (it->second.first == name) {
            // Yes found
            // Push the key in given map
            response.push_back(it->first);
        }
        // Go to next entry in map
        it++;
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: So you want to return a `vector<pair<string, pair<string, string>>>`?

Comment: What is the response supposed to be? You could define a struct for it. You could just do the exact type of the map's members -- pair<string, pair<string, string>>

Comment: I was looking into defining the struct. I considered doing pair<string, pair<string, string>>. Was curious about my other options too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a struct for your `response` and return a `std::vector` of that type.

```
struct Response {
  std::string key;
  std::pair<std::string, std::string> resp_pair;
};

vector<Response> getIfPresentPartOfSpeech(multimap<string, pair<string, string>> dictionary, string name) {
    vector<Response> response;
    auto it = dictionary.begin();
    while (it != dictionary.end()) {
        // Check if value of this entry matches with given value
        if (it->second.first == name) {
            // Yes found
            // Create a Response object
            Response resp;
            resp.key = it->first;
            resp.resp_pair = it->second;
            // Push it in the vector
            response.push_back(resp);
        }
        // Go to next entry in map
        it++;
    }
    return response;
}
```

It's further possible optimize this by using `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` to avoid multiple copies of the container element passing around.

Comment: Thank you! Then I would need to update my prototype to reflect this? so it would be 

vector<Response> getIfPresentName(multimap<string, pair<string, string>> dictionary, string name);

Comment: @javaNoob Yes, you're right. You could have made it `std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::pair<std::string, std::string>>>`, but defining your own `struct` is clean & neat.

Comment: So it seems once I have completed the forward declaration of the getIfPresent function, I am getting the errors C2903,C3203, C2079, and C2371. All tied to the forward declaration I believe. Any suggestions?

Comment: @javaNoob It's hard to tell what the warning are for without having the chance to cast my eyes over the real source code i.e. MCVE of your code. I suppose you're working with MSVC. If you put the `Response` structure definition in a header file and include that header in your source file I assume this should work with no compiler warnings. Again, to further help you I may need an MCVE so that I can verify the warnings you're getting.

Comment: I understand, I really appreciate all the help! I am trying the header file now and it seems it fixed 99% of the errors. Getting some issues from algorithm and xutility now. Most likely due to other parts of my code

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::copy_if` in `<algorithm>` without having to write an explicit loop manually. Also pass `dictionary` by (constant) reference to avoid unnecessary copy:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

// You'll need C++14 to use `auto const& kv` in your lambda expression
std::vector<std::pair<const std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::string>>>
getIfPresentPartOfSpeech(
    const std::multimap<std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::string>>&
        dictionary,
    const std::string& name)
{
    std::vector<
        std::pair<const std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::string>>>
        res;
    std::copy_if(begin(dictionary), end(dictionary), std::back_inserter(res),
                 [&](auto const& kv) { return kv.second.first == name; });
    return res;
}

//test
int main()
{
    std::multimap<std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::string>> dictionary{
        {"first", {"abc", "def"}},
        {"second", {"123", "456"}},
        {"first", {"asdf", "fdas"}},
        {"thrid", {"abc", "123"}},
    };
    auto res = getIfPresentPartOfSpeech(dictionary, "abc");
    for (auto& x : res)
        std::cout << x.first << " " << x.second.first << " " << x.second.second
                  << "\n";
}
```

Using a struct like @aep suggested would be much clearer. You'll need an extra conversion constructor for it to work with `std::copy_if`:

```
struct Response {
    std::string key;
    std::pair<std::string, std::string> value;
    // Provide a conversion constructor that convert your `dictionary` multimap
    // key-value pair into a Response object
    Response(const std::pair<const std::string,
                             std::pair<std::string, std::string>>& kv)
    : key{kv.first}, value{kv.second}
    {}
};

std::vector<Response> getIfPresentPartOfSpeech(
    const std::multimap<std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::string>>&
        dictionary,
    const std::string& name)
{
    std::vector<Response> res;
    std::copy_if(begin(dictionary), end(dictionary), std::back_inserter(res),
                 [&](auto const& kv) { return kv.second.first == name; });
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Edited to reflect OP's comparison.

Comment: Thank you! I am looking through what you suggested, and I am amazed it can be done in so many few lines. Going to make sense of this before I consider implementing myself

Comment: I was thinking along these lines with some typedefs for readability.

Comment: @KennyOstrom could you explain how I can fix the issue with "forward declaration" on the function getIfPresentPartOfSpeech? I used the technique I am familiar with, but it seems like it could be a different process when it comes to using a struct?

Comment: tntxtnt posted the answer. It works for me with just two more includes. The header prototype is just the same, with just a semicolon instead of the {code} part.